# Java HTTPS POST Request Is Returning A Response Code Of 200 When I Know It Should Be Returning A Response Code Of 302

Tags: java, post, https

I'm having trouble making a successful HTTPS POST request.  The request goes through fine but I'm getting a different response than what I receive in my browser.  I'm using an intercepting proxy in my browser to view the requests/responses and I believe that I'm making the exact same request in the code below.  The problem is that the response code is 200(OK) rather than a response code of 301(Redirect).  The redirect is to the page that I want but I can't seem to get there with the code below.  I've tried using 'HttpsURLConnection' but it didn't make a difference.

I'm certain that the request is the same, but it isn't being treated the same.  Could it be that in my browser, the SSL certificate is being used in combination with my cookie, thus making the request different?

How can I get to the desired redirect page?

```
private static void post(){
    try {
        URL obj = new URL("https://www.mywebsiteoffun4321.com/add");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.mywebsiteoffun4321.com");
        con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        String urlParameters = "var=true";
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
}
```

Comment: `HttpURLConnection` follows redirections by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was.  The redirect URL from the POST request in my program wasn't the same as the redirect URL in my browser even though the request was exactly the same.

I was able to get it working by completing the POST request, ignoring the response, and then doing a GET request on the expected URL.  This gave me the response that I expected.

Not sure why the redirect from the POST request is different in my program.